# How to distribute a big package (database) over net in Android?

Tags: java, android, database, synchronization, storage

I need to write app which will be to testing some data (some text and picture - about 500MB). But I want stored the data in database somewhere online (because I want to update it sometime and let application download whole package again)

I found [Parse.com](http://www.parse.com/) to store result, but I didnt find a way to store "the first seed" (big database). I need something like Google Translator (it is donwload some dictionary to use ofline and I trust that it is some kind of database too). Any idea?

Maybe the approach is wrong totally and there is a service which will be hold the data and the application synchronize his state ( internal database ) over internet. I really found nothing ... Thank everyone in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use an **expansion file**.

Comment: I have looked at expansion file and it seems like to by a way but ... I realize that it would be a problem with updating data. I need updated data push to device